# Best practices regarding back and next buttons in Express.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, parse-platform, npm

I’m currently developing a website using the Express web framework. I deploy the website on Parse’s hosted environment, but I’ve other options to host the site to make integration of third-party middleware easier.

I’ve managed to setup a website with login and I can add/get data from the Parse backend. I picked up a book (Express in Action’) and I’ve currently some ideas how to improve the site. I’m using EJS for tempting purposes.

I’m basically asking for some best practices about the following. I retrieve a list of data from the website. Now I want the user to search in this list, select an item, and a click-next-button. In the next screen it’s possible to navigate back using a back button (and remember state). I’ve setup a form with the possible to select an item, but I’m just wondering what’s the easiest way to implement this behavior in a sensible and reliable way. I’ve a hard time locating some easy examples but perhaps I’m searching using the wrong keywords. My exposure to front-end frameworks is limited, but it seems that a combination is AngularJS and Express is one way to go.

Comment: You should be able to do this with routing. The template for the list results should generate urls that link to each result. Since you want the user to select an item then click next you'll need some js on the frontend to figure out which item was selected and get (or generate its url). I recommend looking at jQuery, angular will be overkill.

Comment: Any ideas about saving state between pages? Sessions the way to go?

Comment: yep, sessions are one way to go or url params